# Define which page to open when clicking on Push Notification in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2

My Ionic 2 App is receiving Push Notifications already. When the notification is clicked (app is closed) the app opens and shows the root page.

How can I define another page to show when the app opens after the notification has been clicked?

Ideally I would pass in the push notification another field parameter called 'page' where I can define which page to open.

Right now all I am doing to handle the notifications inside my app is:

```
this.push.rx.notification()
      .subscribe((msg) => {
        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using FCM native and this is works for me,Kindly find one example below - i am set notificationType with `push_chat` then it is goes to `ChatPage` and if push_chat is not set then it goes to Home page

```
import { FCM } from '@ionic-native/fcm';

constructor(private fcm: FCM) {}

...

   this.fcm.onNotification()
      .subscribe((msg) => {
      let messageData = JSON.parse(msg.messageData);
      let ref_this = this;
      if (msg.wasTapped) {
        if(msg.notificationType == 'push_chat') {
            ref_this.nav.setRoot(ChatPage);
        else {
            ref_this.nav.setRoot(Home);
            break;
        }
       });
```

Hope this is helpful to you.